# Why MoveAndSlide does not work with activated AnimationTree in Godot?

Tags: c#, godot

I face new strange problem in godot, when I use MoveAndSlide(I'm using c#), it works smoothly without problem, but when I activate Animation tree, MoveAndSlide doesn't work while debug window show me variables are changing as usual, I have to use Animation tree(Animation Player also same problem), without Animation tree, character will be solid image moves from position to position, I was searching internet for this problem but I did not find any similar problem, I read godot documents, also there is nothing about this problem, I read and watched many tutorials on youtuble about moving 3d person and I use same steps (after changing code from gdscript to c#), also problem don't solved, any one can help?, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys,
The problem was solved by itself in next day, I tried to reproduce the same error again to understand the problem but I failed, I rearranged main character scene then the problem disappeared, how? I don't know.